# Google map api : Multiple sidebar by category doesn't work (text doesn't appear)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps

I want to make the categorized clickable sidebar on google map, but the code doesn't work. No title of marker appears.

First, I made a one-line sidebar like this. [image of a one-line sidebar I made.Check please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lk05.png)
https://jsfiddle.net/kimsngeon/fo70tsmv/9/

Then, I  tried to make multiple sidebars classified by category based on the category of marker which I put. 
Like this image :
[image of what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfOiA.png)

I modified the previous code as below, but the texts of data do not appear. I thought it would be good to compare the category of marker with the id of table box, and then assign each marker to the right sidebar table, but it doesn't work. Could you check is there an error in my logic or code?
https://jsfiddle.net/kimsngeon/fo70tsmv/22/

```js
var map;
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var side_bar_html0 = "";
var side_bar_html1 = "";
var side_bar_html2 = "";
var i=0;


function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: {lat: 37.5515, lng: 126.9250},
          zoom: 15
        });
   addMarker()
}

function addMarker() {
  console.log('creating markers')
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

  geojson_url = 'stores.json'
  //$.getJSON(geojson_url, function(result) {
      // Post select to url.
      var result = jsonData;
      data = result['features']
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][1]),
                parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][0]));
        var title = val['properties']['title']
        var content = val['properties']['title']
        var category = val['properties']['description']
        console.log("title="+title+", content="+content+", category="+category);

        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          title: title,
          category: [category],
          map: map,
          properties: val['properties']
         });

        
        var markerInfo = "<div>" + title + "</br>category: " + category + "</div>"

          marker1.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.close()
          infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo)
          infoWindow.open(map, marker1)
        });
        
        gmarkers1.push(marker1);
        
        //call the id of category of sidebar
        var id_hansik = $('#hansik').val();
        var id_jungsik = $('#jungsik').val();
        var id_yangsik = $('#yangsik').val();
        
        //compare the category of marker with the id of sidebar table, and then assign each marker to right sidebar table
        function showcategory()
        {
            for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++){
                    if(markers1[i].category == idhansik)
                        side_bar_html0 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
                    else if(markers1[i].category == idjungsik)
                        side_bar_html1 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
                    else if(markers1[i].category == idyangsik)
                        side_bar_html2 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
                    
                }
        }
        

        //document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
        document.getElementById("sidebar0").innerHTML = side_bar_html0;
        document.getElementById("sidebar1").innerHTML = side_bar_html1;
        document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML = side_bar_html2;
    
      });
  //});  
}

function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers1[i], 'click');
      }


updateView = function (element) {
   if (element) {
        //Get array with names of the checked boxes
        checkedBoxes = ([...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')]).map(function(o) { return o.id; });
        console.log(checkedBoxes);
        for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
          marker = gmarkers1[i];
            console.log(marker.category)
            //Filter to show any markets containing ALL of the selected options
          if(typeof marker.category == 'object' && checkedBoxes.every(function (o) {
        return (marker.category).indexOf(o) >= 0;})){
              marker.setVisible(true);
          }
            else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
        }
   }
   else {
      console.log('No param given');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() { 
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
    })
  });
    });
// Init map
initMap();
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var jsonData = {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.9288675,37.5490519 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"hansik",
    "title":"h_1",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.9216405,37.5485891 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"hansik",
    "title":"h_2",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.9201695,37.5524256 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"hansik",
    "title":"h_3",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.922562,37.549561 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"jungsik",
    "title":"j_1",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.9187665,37.5519167 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"jungsik",
    "title":"j_2",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.923487,37.548607 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"jungsik",
    "title":"j_3",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.923201,37.550157 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"yangsik",
    "title":"y_1",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.922973,37.551056 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"yangsik",
    "title":"y_2",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 126.924032,37.551597 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "description":"yangsik",
    "title":"y_3",
    "marker-size":"small"
    }
  }
]
}
</script>
<style>

#map-canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}

</style>   
</head>    
<body>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<table border=1>
      <tr>

        <td width = 150 height = 300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
           <input type="checkbox" id="hansik" onchange="updateView(this);"/> hansik
           <div id="sidebar0"></div>
        </td>
        <td width = 150 height = 300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
           <input type="checkbox" id="jungsik" onchange="updateView(this);"/> jungsik
           <div id="sidebar1"></div>
        </td>
        <td width = 150 height = 300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="yangsik" onchange="updateView(this);"/> yangsik
           <div id="sidebar2"></div>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

    
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&v=3&language=ee&dummy=dummy.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Do you call the function `showcategory` anywhere?

Comment: No.. I forgot it. But there is also other problem of markers disappearing when I call the function 'showcategory'.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with the posted code.

1. You aren't calling the `showcategory()` function
2. The `showcategory` function has issues:

```
//compare the category of marker with the id of sidebar table, and then assign each marker to right sidebar table
    function showcategory()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++){
                if(markers1[i].category == idhansik)
                    side_bar_html0 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
                else if(markers1[i].category == idjungsik)
                    side_bar_html1 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
                else if(markers1[i].category == idyangsik)
                    side_bar_html2 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers1.length-1) + ')">' + markers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';

            }
    }


    //document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    document.getElementById("sidebar0").innerHTML = side_bar_html0;
    document.getElementById("sidebar1").innerHTML = side_bar_html1;
    document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML = side_bar_html2;
```

a. `markers1` should be `gmarkers1` (all 6 places)

b. `(gmarkers1.length-1)` should be `i`

c. the `side_bar_htmlX` statements should be inside the function, after the `for` loop.

d. the `idhansik`, `idjungsik` and `idyangsik` should be strings which match those categories.

should be:

```
//compare the category of marker with the id of sidebar table, and then assign each marker to right sidebar table
function showcategory() {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers1[i].category == "hansik")
      side_bar_html0 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
    else if (gmarkers1[i].category == "jungsik")
      side_bar_html1 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
    else if (gmarkers1[i].category == "yangsik")
      side_bar_html2 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';

  }
  //document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  document.getElementById("sidebar0").innerHTML = side_bar_html0;
  document.getElementById("sidebar1").innerHTML = side_bar_html1;
  document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML = side_bar_html2;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1dy9m4tL/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infoWindow;
var side_bar_html0 = "";
var side_bar_html1 = "";
var side_bar_html2 = "";
var i = 0;


function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.5515,
      lng: 126.9250
    },
    zoom: 15
  });
  addMarker()
}

function addMarker() {
  console.log('creating markers')
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

  geojson_url = 'stores.json'
  //$.getJSON(geojson_url, function(result) {
  // Post select to url.
  var result = jsonData;
  data = result['features']
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][1]),
      parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][0]));
    var title = val['properties']['title']
    var content = val['properties']['title']
    var category = val['properties']['description']
    console.log("title=" + title + ", content=" + content + ", category=" + category);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      title: title,
      category: [category],
      map: map,
      properties: val['properties']
    });


    var markerInfo = "<div>" + title + "</br>category: " + category + "</div>"

    marker1.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.close()
      infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo)
      infoWindow.open(map, marker1)
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    //call the id of category of sidebar
    var id_hansik = $('#hansik').val();
    var id_jungsik = $('#jungsik').val();
    var id_yangsik = $('#yangsik').val();

  });
  showcategory();
  //});  
}
//compare the category of marker with the id of sidebar table, and then assign each marker to right sidebar table
function showcategory() {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers1[i].category == "hansik")
      side_bar_html0 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
    else if (gmarkers1[i].category == "jungsik")
      side_bar_html1 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
    else if (gmarkers1[i].category == "yangsik")
      side_bar_html2 += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + gmarkers1[i].title + '<\/a><br>';

  }
  //document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  document.getElementById("sidebar0").innerHTML = side_bar_html0;
  document.getElementById("sidebar1").innerHTML = side_bar_html1;
  document.getElementById("sidebar2").innerHTML = side_bar_html2;
}

function myclick(i) {
  if (gmarkers1[i].getVisible())
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers1[i], 'click');
}


updateView = function(element) {
  if (element) {
    //Get array with names of the checked boxes
    checkedBoxes = ([...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')]).map(function(o) {
      return o.id;
    });
    console.log(checkedBoxes);
    for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
      marker = gmarkers1[i];
      console.log(marker.category)
      //Filter to show any markets containing ALL of the selected options
      if (typeof marker.category == 'object' && checkedBoxes.every(function(o) {
          return (marker.category).indexOf(o) >= 0;
        })) {
        marker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        marker.setVisible(false);
      }
    }
    infoWindow.close();
  } else {
    console.log('No param given');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function() {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
    })
  });
});
// Init map
initMap();
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var jsonData = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.9288675, 37.5490519]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "hansik",
            "title": "h_1",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.9216405, 37.5485891]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "hansik",
            "title": "h_2",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.9201695, 37.5524256]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "hansik",
            "title": "h_3",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.922562, 37.549561]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "jungsik",
            "title": "j_1",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.9187665, 37.5519167]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "jungsik",
            "title": "j_2",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.923487, 37.548607]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "jungsik",
            "title": "j_3",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.923201, 37.550157]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "yangsik",
            "title": "y_1",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.922973, 37.551056]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "yangsik",
            "title": "y_2",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [126.924032, 37.551597]
          },
          "properties": {
            "description": "yangsik",
            "title": "y_3",
            "marker-size": "small"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    #map-canvas {
      width: 600px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  <table border=1>
    <tr>

      <td width=150 height=300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hansik" onchange="updateView(this);" /> hansik
        <div id="sidebar0"></div>
      </td>
      <td width=150 height=300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="jungsik" onchange="updateView(this);" /> jungsik
        <div id="sidebar1"></div>
      </td>
      <td width=150 height=300 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="yangsik" onchange="updateView(this);" /> yangsik
        <div id="sidebar2"></div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>


  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&v=3&language=ee&dummy=dummy.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```